# Issues with successive state object setting in reactjs hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am starting to using react hooks and i decide to put an object instead of a variable in the `useState` function :

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState({
    term: '',
    loading: false,
    ...
});
```

but later when I want to update it

```
const onChange = (e) => { 

    const { value } = e.target;

    setFoo({ ...foo, term: value });

    if(value) setFoo({ ...foo, loading: true });

    ...

}

...

return (
   ...
   <input onChange={onChange} value={term} />
   ...
)
```

**1.** Why in the second `setFoo` when I check the `foo` object I get alway `term` property equal to `''` exactly like the initial value and the input don't get updated with the typed characters ?

**-** When I delete the second `setFoo` it works so I guess because `setFoo` is asynchronous but how to solve this issue ?.

**-** I know that we can workaround this issue by managing to call `setFoo` just once but i want to know other solutions ?

**2.** Why this kinda of issues never happened in `redux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Probably because you have to destruct `foo` instead of `state`

```
setFoo({ ...foo, term: value });
```

[working `useState` example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4q4qnp3lqx)

**2.**  Take a look at the additional hooks, especially [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

> `useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

And your code can become:

```
const reducer = (state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
       case 'loading':
         return { ...state, loading: true };
       case 'loaded':
       default:
         return { ...state, loading: false };
    }
}

const initialState = {
  term: '',
  loading: false,
}
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
dispatch({
   type: e.target.value ? 'loaded' : 'loading'
});
```

[working `useReducer` example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pyn5nxp19x)

Comment: 1. No @Teneff it was just a little typo, 2. but thanks for the `useReducer` advise I will take a look.

Comment: thanks a lot @Teneff ;) just edit your question for the first part cause it was just a typo.

Comment: Look @Teneff  at my edited question there no need for the first part in your answer

Answer (score 2):

The solution: use one `setFoo` like this:

```js
const onChange = (e) => { 

    const { value } = e.target;

    setFoo({ term: value, loading: !!value });

    ...

}
```

`!!` means "convert to boolean value".

Comment: I know that and i just simplified my code the point is how to use successive state object setting in reactjs hooks ?

Comment: I don't know a way to do that with hooks - you must do that in one `setFoo` call.

Comment: Thanks @LorenzHenk anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue by calling `setFoo` only once with all the new key-value pairs, like this:

```
const onChange = (e) => { 

    const { value } = e.target;
    const loading = value ? true : false;
    setFoo({ ...state, term: value, loading });
    ....
}
```

**Update:**

For complex state update and more control on that part, you can use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), and write a separate reducer to update the state.

Comment: I know that and i just simplified my code the point is how to use successive state object setting in reactjs hooks ?

Comment: i think useReducer is what you are looking for, write a separate reducer/function for state update.